# What does Mapping Type Field means in AUTOSAR System Template Document?

Tags: autosar

In the attached snippet from AUTOSAR System Template PDF, please help me understand about all the meaning of Mapping Type Field possible values and end effects as well as significance for users of AUTOSAR based Configuration mechanism.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping type "local" means that the parameter/reference/container has only an impact to the local ECU's behavior and that the parameter/reference/container needs to the configured by an integrator.

The mapping type "full" means that the parameter/reference/container is fully derived from a model element in an upstream template (system model, software-component, diagnostic extract, etc.)

The mapping type "partial" is not (or only in **very** limited quantities) in active use and therefore does not have a sizeable impact on the creation of configuration parameters/references/containers.

Comment: My understanding of `partial` mapping is, that some parts are derived from the Upstream (e.g. Extracts) like with `full` mapping. But, you could also add your own `local` mappings manually, like your own `ComMUser` / `ComMUserPerChannel`.